# avr-gcc inline assembly: Jump to label with runtime offset

Tags: gcc, assembly, label, offset, avr

In avr-gcc inline assembly, how does one jump to a label plus a runtime determined offset? I was thinking I could use this to implement something like a lookup table.

From what I can tell, it's possible by loading the label address to Z register, adding an offset, then using the `ijmp` instruction. But I don't know how to load the label address. This doesn't work:

```
ldi r30,((label)>>0)&0xFF
ldi r31,((label)>>8)&0xFF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the relocatable expression modifiers instead. To quote the [binutils documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/AVR_002dModifiers.html):

```
lo8
    This modifier allows you to use bits 0 through 7 of an address expression
    as 8 bit relocatable expression.
hi8
    This modifier allows you to use bits 7 through 15 of an address expression
    as 8 bit relocatable expression. This is useful with, for example, the AVR
    `ldi' instruction and `lo8' modifier.

    For example

              ldi r26, lo8(sym+10)
              ldi r27, hi8(sym+10)

pm_lo8
    This modifier allows you to use bits 0 through 7 of an address expression
    as 8 bit relocatable expression. This modifier useful for addressing data
    or code from Flash/Program memory. The using of `pm_lo8' similar to `lo8'.
pm_hi8
    This modifier allows you to use bits 8 through 15 of an address expression
    as 8 bit relocatable expression. This modifier useful for addressing data
    or code from Flash/Program memory.
```

Comment: I do however have a concern that this may silently break if gcc decides to put the code beyond 128K flash (yes, I have code bigger than this). But I'll probably ask another question regarding that.

Comment: There is also `pm_hh8` modifier and `EIJMP` instruction, but since your original code also only used 16 bit addressing, I have omitted that for brevity.